# Anaconda with Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use Anaconda with VSCode for Python development, and running into some difficulties.

I followed the steps here: https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration#python-tools-for-visual-studio-ptvs

I can confirm that Python works on my command prompt, and thus I believe (?) that it is properly added to my PATH.

However, when I try to debug in VSCode, I get the error:

```
Failed to launch the Python Process, please validate the path 'python'
Error: spawn python ENOENT
```

I haven't edited my launch.json file at all... do I need to?  I'm guessing it can't find python on the path, why is that?

Comment: Try running `python -c "import os; print(os.getenv('PATH'))"` and see if the directory where Python is installed is included in the output.

Comment: Will do- as an update, on command prompt python is defined (using anaconda's scripts path), but on VSCode built-in terminal, python is not defined (although I thought I added it to PATH, when I run PATH there it doesn't show it).

Answer (score 7):

Turns out I just needed to restart my computer.